# 17.10 Mouse can't click on Gnome Elements, Keyboard Misbehaving

Tags: gnome, keyboard, mouse

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10; it turns out that now I can't click on any elements that are directly GNOME-related: the Dock is dead, and the top panel also doesn't 'see' the mouse, doesn't react to clicks.

The login screen also doesn't react to clicking; the cursor moves just fine.

Inside most windows (Chrome, for instance), clicking is not a problem, and elements I've got lying about on the desktop can be clicked on and work.

The configuration window for the mouse works fine, scrolling and clicking are recognised inside that window, too.

Closing a window is possible only if the app has its own exit dialogue -the usual window operations don't work, apart from a few select apps, such as Chrome (but not Chromium).

I've tried with both my usual wireless mouse and a few wired ones -no difference at all.

As for the keyboard, inside the login screen it works perfectly, but then the number block 'dies', regardless of whether I press the NumBlock key.

I've got a strong feeling the two problems are related.

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

tells me "x11", so it's definitely not a Wayland issue.

I tried connecting two different cabled USB mice using an old PS/2 adapter. This did not work: the mice were simply not recognised. A cursor was visible but didn't move with the mouse.

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Sounds like a stuck key on the keyboard. Can you disconnect the keyboard (laptop too) and try an external keyboard?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but no success. Also, both mouse and keyboard worked perfectly right until the reboot after the upgrade.

Comment: I tried two various suggestions at http://sourcedigit.com/21687-ubuntu-usb-mouse-not-working-ubuntu-touchpad-not-working/ : reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics and setting GRUB to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”i8042.reset quiet splash” . No change.

Comment: The output I get from     less /proc/bus/input/devices    is as follows:

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=c534 Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech USB Receiver"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:12.0-3/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0002/i
nput/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd mouse0 event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=3007f 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bf54444600000000 ffff0001 130f938b17c000 677bfad941dfed 9ed68000004400 10000002
B: REL=1c3
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10

Comment: I got the mouse working doing the following: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` . The keyboard issue still remains, though: it doesn't accept the BlockNum key's orders.

Comment: The keyboard issue was my mistake -I'd enabled "Mouse Keys" in Assistive Technologies. Embarrassing, but it would seem I'm not the first ;-).

Answer (score 7):

Summary for anyone having the same kind of problem: Most likely it's a driver issue, so run

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

in a terminal.

In Assistive Technlogies, Mouse Keys On means you can use the number block + another key I'm not really sure of to do the mouse's job, but in the act you disable the number block as such.

Comment: I think you mean `Num Lock`.

Comment: Yup. Spanish keyboard...

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/968265/89202) resolved it for me:

> If you wish to do it permanently, edit
>
> `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncomment the line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

> Save the file and then on reboot you will never see the cog asking for which session to use.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, but I was definitely using Wayland. Changed it to X.org and it worked straight away. Ubuntu 17.10 with kernel 4.15.rc5

Comment: Same issue here. 'ubuntu-drivers autoinstall' didn't work unfortunately.